# how to make a rigged model move a rigid body object

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, physics

I have rigged arms in a scene and I have a ragdoll. and I want to animate the hand so it can slap the ragdoll around. but when I keyframe the hand to go to where the ragdoll is standing the ragdoll thinks the arm is always where its keyframed and not that it moves from one place to where the ragdoll is standing. I've searched in all Blender forums but I did not see anyone with the same issue I'm having.

Comment: try giving the hand an active rigidbody, and then check the "animated" box in the rigidbody settings

Comment: i already have these settings on and it still bugs out

Comment: could you share your file?

Comment: you can use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Ds84mXVK

Comment: thats fixed now but if the hand enters in contact with the ragdoll the collision of the hand is just way to bad. the ragdoll gets a limb stuck in the hand and has an epilepsy. how do i make the collision better?